# Changing the value of the name attr in input:hidden tag not working - jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, attr

I have the following form (below) which has a hidden input tag. On form submission and response back I want to change the name of that hidden inputs name to have a value of "__REMOVE__". Then on submission of the response of the form again I want it to go back to "__ADD__", and so on. The code however is not working for me, the name="__ADD__" never changes on the form. I'm very new to jQuery so please excuse my ignorance. Note, the value of __BRONZE__ should never change - it is a requirement of the backend PHP that the name changes.

**Form:**

```
<form action="cart.php" method="post" class="cart-ajax">
    <input type="hidden" name="__ADD__" value="__BRONZE__" />
    <br><button type="submit" class="add-more-top dark cart-button-eight">Add to Cart</button>
    <div class="cart-ajax-response"></div>
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// code here snipped out to keep this question short

    // Shopping Cart Form
    $("form.cart-ajax").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this);

            // update the submit buttons text on form submission
            if(form.find('input:hidden').attr('name', '__ADD__'))
            {
                    form.find('button:submit').html('Adding...');
            }
            else if(form.find('input:hidden').attr('name', '__REMOVE__'))
            {
                    form.find('button:submit').html('Removing...');
            }

            $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(),
                    function(data) {

                            // update the submit buttons text after successful response 
                            // update the hidden form field with the opposite of the current value
                            if(form.find('input:hidden').attr('name') == '__ADD__')
                            {
                                    form.find('button:submit').html('Remove');
                                    form.find('input:hidden').attr('name', '__REMOVE__');
                            }
                            else if(form.find('input:hidden').attr('name') == '__REMOVE__')
                            {
                                    form.find('button:submit').html('Add');
                                    form.find('input:hidden').attr('name', '__ADD__');
                            }

                            // do something with the returned data - used in cart-ajax-response div
                            form.find('.cart-ajax-response').empty().html(data.aResults[0]);

                    }, 'json');
    });
}); // <-- document ready
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(form.find('input:hidden').attr('name', '__ADD__'))
```

isn't doing what you think. You're actually setting that field's name not asking if it exists.

Use

```
if(form.find('input[name="__ADD__"]').length)
```

and note `.length` gets you an integer. Without it you'll be returned an object, which is true even if its length is 0.

However, take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/3xTfX/2/ - same thing,  less code

Comment: or just use: if(form.find('input:hidden').attr('name')=='WHATEVER'){...}

Comment: `form.find('input:hidden').attr('name')` returns the name of the first element it matches. It'll work in the example given but another hidden field may be added in that form and could just happen to be before the one we need to check. Things can change so I wouldn't advise relying on something easily breakable.

Comment: Agree, I was just trying to point out that he can actually use the jQuery "attr" function to check if an attribute has certain value, nothing else. I like your answer and your approach, but I just thought that it would be good for CocoaNoob to know that.

Comment: Fair enough but always helpful to point out how a method could be affected by changes made elsewhere if there's a chance it could break.

Comment: Even more if the "name" attribute is going to be changed, provably the best would be to add an "id" to that hidden field.

Comment: Much better idea, would cut out some code. I'm going to jsfiddle it

Comment: Actually a class, because OP has used a class on the form and then form.find() it suggests there's more than the one form on the page. This also means using `('name')=='__ADD__` like Josep suggested too.